# RSpec and FactoryGirl Setup for Testing Carrierwave Uploaders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, carrierwave, factory-bot

I am trying to set up RSpec and FactoryGirl for testing my carrierwave uploaders

**the uploader model code is**

```
# app\models\go_upload.rb
class GoUpload < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :attachment, GoAttachmentUploader
  validates :name, :subname, :person_name, :attachment, presence: true
end
```

**the factory code is** ,referring to https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-test-factories

```
factory :go_upload do
  name "foo"
  subname "bar"
  person_name "testimage"
  attachment  {Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/testfiles/testimage.jpg')))}
end
```

**the GoAttachmentUploader code is**

```
#app\uploaders\go_attachment_uploader.rb
class GoAttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 storage :file

 def store_dir(file="go_contact/#{model.subname}")
  file
 end

 def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end

 def filename
  "#{model.person_name}.jpg"
 end
end
```

The problem is that when I use factory girl to create a go_upload object, all the attributes ("name", "subname" and "person_name") of the object get values expect "attachment" is 'nil'.
I guess the format of "attachment" in database is String, and
{Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/testfiles/testimage.jpg')))} gives hash, so I assign a string to "attachment", but also fail and still get "attachment" nil.

The code works well in development environment, but I am trying to write a test so can anyone help me about this problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a pretty similar setup, please verify `testimage.jpg` exists, also the only one difference with your factory is the following: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'testfiles', 'testimage.jpg'))}

Comment: The "testimage.jpg" exists, and I tried your way but still got 'nil' for attachment.